# calling an external dll dynamically with parameters in cpp

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll

I found this example on MSDN and I am trying to use it but I am having issues getting it to work with parameters ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944%28VS.85%29.aspx))

Below is the code I am trying to use and the method I am trying to call has 4 parameters (CString a, CString b, CString c, BOOL d).

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall 
    ImportFile(CString a, CString b, CString c, BOOL d)
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\MyDll.dll")); 

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.
    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "TestFunction"); 

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.
        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
            (ProcAdd) (a, b, c, d); 
        }
        // Free the DLL module.
        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function
    if (!fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What fails? I suspect the call to `LoadLibrary()` as the backslash is not escaped in the DLL's path.

Comment: Where is your code failing? Is GetProcAddress returning NULL?

Comment: I'm getting a compile error C2197: 'MYPROC' : too many arguments for call

Comment: Just figured it out. was missing the typedef args for the params.

Comment: this question just made my day

Answer (score 4):

I got it working now.. I was missing the extra params in the typedef defined:

```
typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(CString a, CString b, CString c, BOOL d);
```

Comment: The `typedef` is not in the posted answer code, making it impossible for anyone to assist. At least you found it anyway!

Comment: Congrats but you should check the whole code prior to posting on it here.